# NSXMLParser ignore XML's DTD

Tags: ios, xml, swift, nsxmlparser

I faced problem when parse XML in iOS App. I define DTD to remove white spaces and tabs.
This is my xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE list [
<!ELEMENT list (bsinfo+)>
<!ELEMENT bsinfo (id,title,desc,books)>
<!ELEMENT id (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT desc (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT books (book+) >
<!ELEMENT book (idu, pages) >
<!ELEMENT idu (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT pages (#PCDATA)>
]>

<list>
<bsinfo>
<id>16</id>
<title>X</title>
<desc>none</desc>
    <books>

        <book>
            <idu>123</idu>
            <pages>567</pages>
        </book>
        <book>      
            <idu>874</idu>
            <pages>256</pages>
        </book>             
    </books>        
</bsinfo>   
</list>
```

and when i parsed it still got white space and tabs in:

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, foundCharacters string: String!)
{
        println(xmlElement + " => [" + string+"]")
}
```

Result:

```
id => [16]
id => [
    ]
title => [X]
title => [
    ]
...
```

Why NSXMLParser doesn't recognize DTD?

Comment: The DTD provides info re structure of the elements and attributes of the XML and not spaces/tabs - which part of the DTD deals with spaces?

Comment: I'm follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539802/why-is-nsxmlparser-picking-up-this-whitespace-in-the-foundcharacters-method that lead to this http://www.cafeconleche.org/books/xmljava/chapters/ch06s10.html